# Python: Making a script run for a specified amount of time

Tags: python

I found a script that connects to a water flow meter and records data. The script runs on an infinite loop as is but I am trying to make it only run for 5 minutes. I've had a go at altering it and here is what I've done. The code that I have altered is towards the bottom:

```
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
  
class FlowMeter():
    ''' Class representing the flow meter sensor which handles input pulses
        and calculates current flow rate (L/min) measurement
    '''
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.flow_rate = 0.0
        self.last_time = datetime.now()
  
    def pulseCallback(self, p):
        ''' Callback that is executed with each pulse 
            received from the sensor 
        '''
       
        # Calculate the time difference since last pulse recieved
        current_time = datetime.now()
        diff = (current_time - self.last_time).total_seconds()
       
        # Calculate current flow rate
        hertz = 1. / diff
        self.flow_rate = hertz / 7.5
       
        # Reset time of last pulse
        self.last_time = current_time
    
    def getFlowRate(self):
        ''' Return the current flow rate measurement. 
            If a pulse has not been received in more than one second, 
            assume that flow has stopped and set flow rate to 0.0
        '''
       
        if (datetime.now() - self.last_time).total_seconds() > 1:
            self.flow_rate = 0.0
        
        return self.flow_rate
  
def main():
    ''' Main function for repeatedly collecting flow rate measurements
        and sending them to the SORACOM API
    '''
   
    # Configure GPIO pins
    INPUT_PIN = 7
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(INPUT_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
   
    # Init FlowMeter instance and pulse callback
    flow_meter = FlowMeter()
    GPIO.add_event_detect(INPUT_PIN,
                          GPIO.RISING,
                          callback=flow_meter.pulseCallback,
                          bouncetime=20)
    end_time = datetime + (60 * 5)
    while True:
  
        datetime < end_time
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        flow_rate = flow_meter.getFlowRate()
        print('Timestamp: %s' % timestamp)
        print('Flow rate: %f' % flow_rate)
        # Delay
        time.sleep(5)
        if datetime > end_time:
            break
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Visual Studio code tells me there are no issues with the script but now when I run it, it just starts and immediately stops. I am quite new to Python and am struggling with the basics. I feel like what I'm trying to do isn't terribly complicated, I just don't have the skills.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line of code: `datetime < end_time`?

Comment: Starts and immediately stops or raises an exception? This shouldn't run.

Comment: What should happen if the code is in the middle of doing something important when time runs out? Under what exact conditions is it permitted to stop, and how should it check the timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few bugs in your code.

First, when you run `from datetime import datetime`, the `datetime` you import is a `type`. Meaning, `endtime = datetime + (60 * 5)` doesn't make sense. In actuality, you want to add five minutes to the current time. Additionally, the `datetime` module here is overkill and requires some extra work with timedelta's to get it to function properly. Instead, just use the `time` module. It would look like this:

```
import json
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
  
class FlowMeter():
    ''' Class representing the flow meter sensor which handles input pulses
        and calculates current flow rate (L/min) measurement
    '''
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.flow_rate = 0.0
        self.last_time = time.time()
  
    def pulseCallback(self, p):
        ''' Callback that is executed with each pulse 
            received from the sensor 
        '''
       
        # Calculate the time difference since last pulse recieved
        current_time = time.time()
        diff = int(current_time - self.last_time)  
       
        # Calculate current flow rate
        hertz = 1. / diff
        self.flow_rate = hertz / 7.5
       
        # Reset time of last pulse
        self.last_time = current_time
    
    def getFlowRate(self):
        ''' Return the current flow rate measurement. 
            If a pulse has not been received in more than one second, 
            assume that flow has stopped and set flow rate to 0.0
        '''
    
        if time.time() - self.last_time > 1:
            self.flow_rate = 0.0

        return self.flow_rate
  
def main():
    ''' Main function for repeatedly collecting flow rate measurements
        and sending them to the SORACOM API
    '''
   
    # Configure GPIO pins
    INPUT_PIN = 7
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(INPUT_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
   
    # Init FlowMeter instance and pulse callback
    flow_meter = FlowMeter()
    GPIO.add_event_detect(INPUT_PIN,
                          GPIO.RISING,
                          callback=flow_meter.pulseCallback,
                          bouncetime=20)
    end_time = time.time() + (60 * 5)
    while True:
        timestamp = str(datetime.now())
        flow_rate = flow_meter.getFlowRate()
        print('Timestamp: %s' % timestamp)
        print('Flow rate: %f' % flow_rate)
        # Delay
        time.sleep(5)
        if time.time() > end_time:
            break
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Thank you! Made edits and it ran successfully for 5 mins! I really should actually take a python course....

Answer (score 2):

There are a few parts:

1. set your *stop* time (e.g.)

```
end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=5)
```

2. evaluate the condition

```
if datetime.now() > end_time:
```

3. cleanup: remove this line (what does it do...??)

```
datetime < end_time
```

and the pre-requisites:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```